# What kind of (x)HTML tags does CKEditor allow?

Tags: html, wysiwyg, ckeditor

What kind of (x)HTML tags does [CKEditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) allow? And which tags don't they allow to be used?

Answer (score 2):

CKEditor doesn't filter on tags. You could write a plugin to do that, but the best way is to filter your data at the server with a tool like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)